# Java: Trying to use a while loop to check scanner input for an int variable, not sure how to initialize the variable?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

This is one of the first programs I've written on my own. I'm writing a program to tell you what your zodiac sign is, and I got the program to run with a scanner method that I imported, but the problem I'm running into is now that I'm trying to check user input using a while loop, it's not running as I intended and as I compile my code the error I'm running into is that my variable of type int is not initialized. I wrote it when declaring it with no assigned value, and I'm unsure of what I should be assigning it to fix this issue.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyStarSign {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
System.out.println("What month were you born?");

String birthMonth = "";

    

birthMonth= myScanner.next();  // Read user input



System.out.println("You were born in " + birthMonth + "?");  // Output user input

System.out.println("What day of the month were you born?");

int birthDay;

    while (birthDay > 31) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a valid day of the month");

        birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();
    
    }
```

This is what my code looks like as of right now ^^

Now for my attempted solution:

int birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();

```
    while (birthDay > 31) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a valid day of the month");

        birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();
    
    }
```

This was what I attempted to fix the issue, though I'm running into the same issue again when compiling my code

Answer (score 0):

Initialize means it needs to have an initial value, like this:

```
int birthDay = 0;
```

So the only thing you need is to add a value to your variable

**EDIT:** try out this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyStarSign 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("What month were you born?");

        String birthMonth = "";

        birthMonth= myScanner.next();  // Read user input

        System.out.println("You were born in " + birthMonth + "?");  // Output user input

        System.out.println("What day of the month were you born?");

        int birthDay = 0;

        while (birthDay > 31) 
        {

            System.out.println("Please enter a valid day of the month");

            birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried that since posting this question, but I'm getting the same error. But I suspect it's from a different issue right now because in my terminal when I compile my code it was giving me the same error even after deleting the while loop, pointing to the while loop that no longer existed even though I made sure to save my code

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Which IDE or editor are you using? Are you sure you are saving the changes? Which error does displays? I did copy your code to run it. The problem may be on that

Comment: In your code there missing brackets, I assumed you just forgot them, but I will add a code I'd tested for you to copy it and run

Comment: I'm relatively certain it's not missing brackets, prior to the addition of the while loop the program ran just fine with no issues and worked as intended, the while loop is the only thing I touched since opening my text editor tonight

Comment: I'm just compiling it using javac MyStarSign.java

Comment: If the code I gave you dosen't work, the problem relies somewhere outside it. Please show the error that the compiler gives you

Comment: I put in the initialized in birthDay = 0; now it seems like my if statements following the while loop are not running and I have to figure out why

Comment: Its beacuse you ain't reading from user any value and birthDay is 0, so when while loop is reached, birthDay is less than 31 returning false, making while loop no to execute, you need to scan it before it enters the loop or use a do while statement

Comment: I assume your code is alredy running, the consequent problems are just logical. You can mark this question as solved if you think it is

Comment: In order to scan a value to birthDay you can replace `int birthDay = 0` to ` int birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();` or scan it next to declaration

Comment: I appreciate all the help, misread your comment at first. My program is running as intended, now on to attempting to account for user error for birthMonth which I'm a bit intimidated by as I'm not sure where to begin when trying to check for spelling errors considering it's of type String

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    System.out.println("What month were you born?");

    String birthMonth = "";

    birthMonth= myScanner.next();  // Read user input

    System.out.println("You were born in " + birthMonth + "?");  // Output user input
    System.out.println("What day of the month were you born?");

    int birthDay;
    birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();

    while (birthDay > 31) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid day of the month");
        birthDay = myScanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting code, explain what it does and how it answers the question.